# OpenID and federated logins

Tags: google-app-engine, openid, google-openid

The federated login works, now how do I enable OpenID logins like .blogspot.com? I've misunderstood how to enable federated logins and OpenID same time. Are these 2 different cases and can get combined? I can enable federated login with very little code. Then my openid I must've misunderstood since it links to google. Here's how I tried app.yaml

```
- url: /_ah/login_required
  script: do_openid_login.py
```

and code

```
  loginmsg = loginmsg + '<a href=\"%s\">OpenID</a>' % (users.create_login_url("/"))
```

It leads to google login. What can you recommend? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenID and federated login are the same thing. Did you enable them in your admin console of your app? Have you read the section on OpenID in [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/overview.html#Authentication_Options)?

Comment: It works leaving me to wish clearer documentation on passing the claimid parameter. Thank you Nick Johnson